# How do you view a sql.gz file as plain text SQL from the command line?

Tags: command-line, mysql, tar, gzip

How do you view a sql.gz file as plain text SQL from the command line?

I want to read the SQL statements stored in a `.sql.gz` file, from the command line on the server. I've tried `tar -xzvf`, but get `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`. `cat` returns garbage because it's compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gunzip -c <filename> | less
```

or

```
zcat <filename> | less
```

Comment: On systems that provide the `lesspipe` preprocessor, you should be able to invoke `less` directly on a `.gz` file and have the decompression handled behind the scenes - see `man lesspipe`

Answer (score 2):

`zcat file.sql.gz` will output the file to stdout, which then can be combined with `grep` or `more` or `less` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Much of the time, and probably in this case, just plain `less` will do the right thing. This uses the so-called `less` preprocessor. So, do

```
less file.sql.gz
```

This won't actually write the file in plain text to the filesytem; it is for your viewing pleasure only, but much of the time that is enough. I personally find the `less` preprocesor quite useful. It saves me from remembering a bunch of commands. On Debian, at least, the less preprocessor is `/usr/bin/lesspipe`. This is a shell script. This location of this can possibly be found by checking the value of the enviroment variable LESSOPEN. e.g.

```
echo $LESSOPEN
|/usr/bin/lesspipe %s
```

The relevant part of this script for just a gzipped text file is:

```
                 # Note that this is out of alpha order so that we don't catch
                    # the gzipped tar files.
                    *.gz|*.z|*.dz)
                            gzip -dc "$1" ;;
```

This is with `less` version 444-4 on Debian wheezy.